# Retrieve date on which a list of SQL server databases went offline

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a list of offline databases on my SQL servers. I am able to retrieve the list of offline DB and there status using the SQL code below.

But I am unable to find their corresponding time and login at which they went offline.

I have tried using the stored procedure sp_readerrorlog as well but was unable to retrieve the required details

```
SELECT 'DB_NAME' = db.name,'FILE_NAME' = mf.name,'FILE_TYPE' = mf.type_desc,
       'FILE_PATH' = mf.physical_name
FROM sys.databases db
   INNER JOIN sys.master_files mf ON db.database_id = mf.database_id
WHERE db.state = 6
```

I am expecting the result to be as follows

```
servername    db_name    status   offline_date  login_name
sonsql01      saion     offline   28/02/19     flore\sonal
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When was a Database taken Offline](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89815/when-was-a-database-taken-offline)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sys.databases contains the status of every database but does not indicate when it went offline. The Windows Application Log does have an entry for every time a  db is started or stopped which include the date.

This script, which I edited a bit,  taken from SQLCentral will give you the information you want but you need permissions to execute XP commands:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
GO
-- Search all sql error logs at once
DECLARE @SearchString1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ,@SearchString2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ,@LogType INT
        ,@Path VARCHAR(512)
        ,@StartTime DATE
        ,@EndTime   DATE = GETDATE();
-- ----------------------------------------------------------
SET @SearchString1 = 'offline' --leave blank for everything
SET @SearchString2 = '' --leave blank for everything
SET @LogType = 1        -- =SQL Server log, 2=SQL Agent log
SET @StartTime = dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, @EndTime) - 1, 0)
-- ----------------------------------------------------------
SELECT @Path = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([PATH]), 
                        CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE([path])), 260)) + N'LOG.trc'
    FROM sys.traces 
    WHERE is_default = 1;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#EnumLogs','U') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #EnumLogs;
    END;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Logger','U') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #Logger;
    END;
CREATE TABLE #EnumLogs
    (
        [ArchiveNum] INT
    , LogDate DATETIME
    , LogSizeInBytes INT
    );
INSERT INTO #EnumLogs 
    EXECUTE xp_enumerrorlogs @LogType
-- Iterate around all the logs gathering results
CREATE TABLE #Logger
    (
        LogDate DATETIME
    , ProcessInfo NVARCHAR(MAX)
    , LogText NVARCHAR(MAX)
    );
DECLARE @Counter INT
DECLARE errlogs CURSOR
    LOCAL STATIC FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY
    FOR SELECT el.ArchiveNum
        FROM #EnumLogs el;
OPEN errlogs;
FETCH NEXT FROM errlogs INTO @Counter;
WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO #Logger 
      EXECUTE xp_readerrorlog
         @Counter
        ,@LogType             
        ,@SearchString1       
        ,@SearchString2       
    FETCH NEXT FROM errlogs INTO @Counter;
END
CLOSE errlogs;
DEALLOCATE errlogs;
SELECT @@servername as SvrName
        ,gt.StartTime AS EventTimeStamp 
        ,gt.LoginName
        ,gt.DatabaseName
        ,L.LogText
    FROM ::fn_trace_gettable( @path, DEFAULT ) gt
    INNER JOIN sys.trace_events te
        ON gt.EventClass = te.trace_event_id
        INNER JOIN sys.trace_categories tc
            ON te.category_id = tc.category_id
        INNER JOIN sys.trace_subclass_values tv
            ON gt.EventSubClass = tv.subclass_value
            AND gt.EventClass = tv.trace_event_id
        INNER JOIN #Logger L
            ON REPLACE(REPLACE(l.ProcessInfo,'spid',''),'s','') = gt.spid
            AND CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME,l.LogDate) = CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME,gt.StartTime)
    WHERE 1 = 1
        AND ObjectType = 16964
        AND te.name = 'Object:Altered'
    ORDER BY gt.StartTime DESC;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#EnumLogs','U') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #EnumLogs;
    END;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Logger','U') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #Logger;
    END;
```